# Change navbar color when the dropdown menu is open

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navbar that changes color when scrolling down, ie. it is transparent at the beginning and after the scroll becomes blue. I used the following js code:

```
$(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
      var $nav = $(".navbar-fixed-top");
      $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
    });
});
```

My aim is to change the color (ie. add the class 'scrolled') also when the dropdown menu is open.

Otherwise, if I'm using the mobile phone and I visit the site.. If the site is no scrolled the navbar is transparent and the same is for the dropdown menu, but I want to avoid it.

Is there a possibility to add in this js code the condition "add class scrolled" when the dropdown menu is open?

Thank you so much and sorry for the easy question, but it is the first time for me dealing with js.
Manuel

Comment: I  think you want to change the CSS so that the navbar isn't invisible ever on small screen, rather than do anything with JS

Comment: @Popnoodles It could be a solution, but I would like to have the effect "invisible at the beginning, colored when you scroll down" also in the phone... but to do that I have to make the navbar colored even if the dropdown menu is opened.. Do you think that it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you have *bg-light* or any *bg-** class added in your navbar, it won't allow you to set background-color explicitly. Try removing the class as;

#### Html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
```

#### Css

```
<style>
    .scrolled {
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
```

Make sure you are picking up the correct class selector ***".navbar-fixed-top"***

Comment: Hi, thank you. The code is working and the color changes when I scroll down. My problem concern the js code and the possibility to use that code also when a user opens the dropdown menu. Is it possible? (I mean, another js function to change the color of the navbar when the dropdown menu is opened)

Comment: Yes, that's possible

Comment: Thanks Asif, and do you know which is the javascript code for doing that?

Comment: Create a trigger function that will toggle class based on condition like, if the dropdown is open you'd have _show_ class added by bootstrap, check if _show_ class exists using hasClass(), and based on it toggle the class of your navbar